# angular- data-ng-bind-html - how its work

Tags: angularjs

need help in understand data-ng-bind-html.
is it always safe to do:

```
         <div data-ng-bind-html="pageHtml"></div>
```

what happen if pageHtml come from users and contein scripts or even just html code that can change the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you check it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml You will get into $sanitaze, sanitazor runs through the code and removes possible injections and unsafe content like scripts or js executions, but after all I'd suggest: `trust no one`